# Setting environment variables in cmd.exe

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Below are instructions I am following for setting environment variables:

> Next you'll need to set a couple of environmental variables. You can
>   do this at the command line or you can set it up in your
>   computer's/master node's bash_rc/bash_profile files.
>
> export SPARK_HOME="$HOME/Downloads/spark-1.3.1"

I open cmd.exe and type in the command above and I get 'export' is not a recognized command. How do I use cmd.exe to set SPARK_HOME? The site I am using to install pyspark is: https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/apache-spark/

Comment: This command is a LINUX command. In Windows you need to use SET SPARK_HOME="PutDirectoryHere". But take care: The path has to be in windows format as well, not the forward slash linux type of path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

Setting up an environment variable through CMD:

Open CMD

```
Set Spark_Home="$HOME/Downloads/spark-1.3.1"
```

Now test by just entering %Spark_Home% in CMD and hit enter.

Comment: You need to use `setx` to set the value permanently. `set` applies only to the **current** `cmd` shell.

Answer (score 1):

For setting an environment variable for the **current user** (windows account):

1. close your current cmd shell/terminal;
2. access **Run** (press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>);
3. type `setx HOME %userprofile%` (for example);
4. press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Voilá, you can now reopen the cmd shell and type `set HO` to check all variables starting with `HO`.

Alternatively, if you prefer to access the window to check all of them, **run**:

- `%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl EditEnvironmentVariables`

*Note*: in OP's specific case, the command for setting would be:

- `setx SPARK_HOME "%userprofile%\Downloads\spark-1.3.1"`

For more information, type in cmd shell `setx /?`.